# Add list of numbers like an accountant

Tags: arithmetic

How can I add a list of numbers like an accountant would (using presumably `bc` or `dc`)? Typically this is done by entering each number followed by a "+" key, e.g., there would be on an adding machine. I tried

```
300[RET]<br>
521+[RET]
```

and got a syntax error. The same thing happens if I put the plus sign first:

```
300[RET]<br>
+521[RET]
```

I do not want to make a long line of numbers separated by plus signs.

Comment: Your first example works for me as-is in `dc`.

Comment: @Celada work as is, but you need to enter `p` to print result.

Comment: So how do you want to print the result ? Can you show an example with more numbers - say 3 or 4 ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `dc`

```
dc
300
521+p
```

which pushes 300 then 521 onto the stack, then pops and adds them (`+`) and `p`rints the answer: `821`. Continuing the sequence with more postfix additions:

```
123+
456+
```

and then printing the final result

```
p
```

outputs `1400` (i.e. 821 + 123 + 456). You can exit the dc interpreter by typing `q`. So the full transcript is:

```
dc
300
521+p
821
123+
456+
p
1400
q
```